# Update the number of rows based on multi where conditions across tables

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have two tables: [Invoices], which has a field on Vendor ID "i_v_id," and [Inventory_adjustment], which has columns Debit, Credit, and flag value which is set to 0 by default.
In this situation, I need to update every row in the inventory_adjustment database that fits the WHERE requirements.

I tried several methods to update the rows, but they all resulted in error warnings.

> Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near '.`inad_invoice_id` SET inad_adjusted_flag = 1
> WHERE `IA`.`inad_date` >= '2022-12' at line 1 UPDATE
> `inventory_adjustment IA JOIN invoices I ON I`.`i_id =`
> `IA`.`inad_invoice_id` SET inad_adjusted_flag = 1 WHERE
> `IA`.`inad_date` >= '2022-12-25' AND `IA`.`inad_date` <= '2023-01-03'
> AND `I`.`i_v_id` = '3'

Model

```
function Adjustment()
    {
        
        $data=array(
            'IA.inad_adjusted_flag' => "1"
        );
        $datefrom = $this->input->post('datefrom');
        $dateto = $this->input->post('dateto');
        $this->db->where('IA.inad_date >=', $datefrom);
        $this->db->where('IA.inad_date <=', $dateto);
        $this->db->where('I.i_v_id', $this->input->post('vendor_id'));
        $this->db->update('inventory_adjustment IA JOIN invoices I ON I.i_id = IA.inad_invoice_id',$data);
        if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think there is a missing comma between the 2 tables you want to update... check if `inventory_adjustment, IA` works?

Comment: Unfortunately, not works

Comment: I've never used a UPDATE with a JOIN, but I've joined tables using `$this->db->join('table to join', 'join_conditions)`. Try if it works